# ARM Assembly, first instruction upload

Tags: assembly, arm, gameboy, game-boy-advance

I'm trying to learn arm assemly, it will be the first programming language that i can actually say i know.   actually right now im learning the machine language first since its easier for me.

My question is:  How do i load my first instruction into the processor?

My programming platform to experiment on is a gameboy advance.  It has an arm7tdmi processor and i don't have a flashcard so i'm going to use my arduino to upload code through the link port (connected to the chip's d, di, do, dc pins.)   i just need help figuring out how to upload any program.  without using anyone else's software other than arduino stuff, and the gameboy bios.

So my question is:
if i take the bios chip out of the gba, can i still upload instructions through these  pins, or is   there  a different place the processor normally looks for instructions once piwered on?  also how does it accept communication and how do i upload an instruction one bit at a time?

Comment: Yes, the processor normally looks for instructions in the BIOS chip. And the BIOS chip's code is probably how it knows to look at the link port. So if you remove the BIOS chip you won't be able to use the link port (or the cartridge, or anything)... also isn't the BIOS built into the processor chip?

Answer (score 3):

the mechanism to use that port is called multiboot, your arduinio is going to have to conform to the right protocol to make that work and no doubt someone has done it already.

now removing the bios if you could wouldnt do you any good

for a gba you have to have the right signature at the beginning of your data for the bios to allow it to run then it runs your first instruction at the first word in that memory which you need to have a jump there.

Basically the gba is a great platform for learning bare metal, but the way you are doing it or talking about doing it is not the best way to go for this kind of learning.

if you want to use the gba use visualboyadvance the emulator/simulator and get over the hurdle of booting and running your first programs which are probably going to need to draw pixels in that environment (on a gba blinking the battery low led is the easiest, but without a flash cart, dont bother just yet).

for visual boy advance you may or may not have to have the right signature but there is gobs and gobs of info and examples out there that show what the header needs to be to work and/or tools that if you leave the right space will patch your binary to make it work.

for the real hardware not only do you have to get the timing and pullups and such right on that serial port, but you also have to have the right header to get a multiboot program to run.  it is definitely not beginner stuff for the gba.  find a flash cart they are still out there, my favorite for a while is the ezflash 3 in 1 gba sized one not the ds sized one but you need a ds with a ds flash cart to load something on it. ds flash carts are much easier to come by (but ds development is a little harder but not so much).  there are also some m3 orwhatever they are called sdcard or micro sd card based ones that you dont need a fancy programmer (whose software is hard to come by and obsoletes fast) for.

you might consider a ds lite (older one) and a cart for that they are easy to come by

or just get a tiva c launchpad or some other $5 or $10 arm board

the best is just use an instruction set simulator first, free, and you can be developing minutes after reading this. use the armulator in gdb.

short answer you have the wrong hardware for the kind of thing you are trying to do.  but very good hardware for learning bare metal programming (so long as you can get a flash cart that isnt painful to use).  My preferred solution is putting a bootloader on the flash cart then turning that top port into an 8n1 serial port, which takes a link cable that you cut in half to get at the wires and wired those to an ftdi usb to serial board.  then you only need to load the bootloader once if you find mine or someone elses, and for a long time dont need to remove or reprogram the cartridge. just power cycle (or reset if you add a reset button) and serially download your program and run it.

Comment: alternatively if you can find the boot prom you can remove it and replace it with a socket, get a prom programmer for the prom (might have to buy another prom depending on the condition getting it off and if it is an otp or not), those sockets dont last very long.  the arduino is not involved.

Comment: also remember that arduinos are often 5V not 3.3 and in gba mode that port is 3.3v so you can do some damage to the gba or arduino or both if you use a 5v arduino without voltage converters, and since I think one pin is bidirectional in multiboot mode that makes life more painful when trying to do voltage conversion, easier to just buy a 3.3v arduino.

Comment: Well i was thinking about removing the bios chip because i'm more interested in the processor itself, and writing my own sort of bios.  Probably more of a hassle than its worth though.  Yes i know there's a voltage difference and have already set up voltage dividing circuit

Comment: I dont see how the arduino could keep up or have enough pins...just get a $10 board like the tiva c launchpad or stm32f0 or f4 discovery, etc.

Comment: realhotstuff has one cartridge type left it appears the m3 minisd pro for $11.

Comment: oh and an ez flash iv for the gba as well which appears to support an sd card, usually the ez flash needs a programmer (which this may or may not come with)

Comment: I'm deadset on sending a program (of any kind) through multiboot.  I know it's not beginner stuff but i'm willing to learn and have been searching through articles and files for about a month now.  I want to learn "bare metal" programming,  that's my goal.   If you can point me to documentation on headers, pullups, and timing, and where that serial port is, that'd be great.   i understand timing already if i'm not mistaken, it was in the processor manual.

Comment: Ive seen two people do it, one guy used some weird development board, and another guy used an arduino leonardo.

Comment: right, been there used that, but for multiboot you dont feed it just one instruction, you feed it the whole program including the header, then you start it then the program runs. it is the ideal interface for what you want if you can get a working loader (and you can write gba programs that work when loaded over this interface)

Comment: I've ended up buying the stm32f0 like dwelch suggested.  Feeling pretty confident on learning it.  Only real mystery I have left in my head is "How do I interact with the pins via peripheral address space?".  I'm guessing perephrals are set up dfferently for each m0 processor so me would need to loo up datasheet for ths specfc one.   typer board be messed up... srry